# How to send CSRF Cookie from React to Django Rest Framework with Axios

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios, csrf, django-csrf

I want to make a **POST** request from a **React** app using **Axios** to a **Django Rest Framework** backend. I have managed to get a **CSRF Token** from the backend but I can't manage to send it with my request, so I always get a `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)` error:

This is the code of my **React** app:

```
handleClick() {
    const axios = require('axios');
    var csrfCookie = Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN');
    console.log(csrfCookie)
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/es/api-auth/login/',
      {
        next: '/',
        username: 'admin@admin.com',
        password: 'Cancun10!',
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'x-xsrf-token': csrfCookie,  // <------- Is this the right way to send the cookie?
        },
        withCredentials = true,
      }
    )
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

And this is my `settings.py` CSRF configuration:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'xsrfheadername',
    'xsrfcookiename',
    'content-type',
    'XSRF-TOKEN',
)

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = serverconfig.CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = serverconfig.CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XSRF-TOKEN"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django uses `X-CSRFTOKEN` as the csrf header by default, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#csrf-header-name). The option `CSRF_COOKIE_NAME` you use in your Django settings only changes the cookie name, which by default is `csrftoken`, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-name).

To solve your issue, use this header in your axios call: `headers: { 'X-CSRFTOKEN': csrfCookie }`.

Use the following:

```
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/es/api-auth/login/',
    {
        next: '/',
        username: 'admin@admin.com',
        password: 'Cancun10!',
    },
    {
        headers: {
             'X-CSRFTOKEN': csrfCookie,
         },
    },
)
```

Also, remove `XSRF-TOKEN` from `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS` in your Django settings, and add `X-CSRFTOKEN` to it instead. If you don't feel like removing `XSRF-TOKEN`, you can safely add `X-CSRFTOKEN` to `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS` with the following, documentation [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)

```
# settings.py

from corsheaders.defaults import default_headers

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = list(default_headers) + [
    'X-CSRFTOKEN',
]
```

Comment: I tried your answer, and I didn't get an error from the backend (this is the backend console result: `"OPTIONS /es/api-auth/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0`), but the frontend console reports an error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/es/api-auth/login/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-csrftoken is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response`

Comment: @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto Try adding `X-CSRFTOKEN` to `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS` in Django settings.

Comment: I did it, and I got back to the original point (`Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)`)

Comment: @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto Try adding `withCredentials: True` to the axios config (after headers).

Comment: I was making a mistake. Now it is working, but I get another error: `Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)`)

Comment: There was a typo - use `X-CSRFTOKEN` instead of `X-XCSRFTOKEN`.

Comment: Your solution works, but I found that the name of the cookie must be `x-xsrf-token`

Comment: @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto that doesn't seem right. After looking at the axios source code, it seems that all you have to do is add the headers as shown in my answer. You don't want to use `x-xsrf-token` in the headers because that's not the header name, it's the cookie name. Also, make sure `Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')` exists. I can help you over chat if needed be.

Comment: Can we use this X-CSRFTOKEN without username and password. Because I am using this with Google Oauth.

Answer (score 5):

Also, it's will be easier if you create an Axios instance

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  withCredentials: true,
  xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFToken',
  xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
})
```

And make sure `xsrfCookieName` and `CSRF_COOKIE_NAME` have the same name. Note that if `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` set to True, client-side JavaScript will not be able to access the CSRF cookie:

```py
# settings.py

CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "csrftoken"
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False

CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = ["Content-Type", "X-CSRFToken"]
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```