# axios.delete not working in react.JS ERROR code 403 forbidden

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

i am developing a project using DRF and react js not delete using drf working fine but by axios.delete giving 403 error.

actions/review.js

```
export const deleteReview = (id) => dispatch => {
axios
    .delete(`/api/review/${id}`)
    .then(res => {
        dispatch({
            type: DELETE_REVIEW, 
            payload: id
        })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

}

reducers/review.js

```
case DELETE_REVIEW:
    return {
        ...state,
        review: state.review.filter(review => review.id !== action.payload)
    }
```

main review file

```
<tbody>
{ this.props.review.map(review => (
<tr key={review.id}>
    <td>{review.id}</td>
    <td>{review.city_name}</td>
    <td>{review.traveller_name}</td>
    <td>{review.traveller_review}</td>
    <td>{review.review_img}</td>
    <td><button onClick = {this.props.deleteReview.bind(this, review.id)}className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Show us the server-side code! Because, that's where 403 response is coming from, right?

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54097524/how-to-send-csrf-cookie-from-react-to-django-rest-framework-with-axios - looks like you're missing CSRF.